# How to have simple animated shapes that don't keep changing/blinking color in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, animation

I have some code I wrote for fun that draws lines of circles with different colors. Without using a Swing Timer, the circles are drawn "all at once" and they alternate color between red, green, blue and yellow. So, without the timer, the code works as expected. However, when I try animating so that I can see the circles being drawn, which means using a Swing Timer for the loop instead of a while/for loop, the circles all have the same color and keep blinking the four colors all together. I guess the problem is color is not associated with each object but with the whole frame, since I'm changing the color of the frame every few milliseconds the circles that have already been drawn don't remain with their original color like they did with the while loop. If you see any solution for this, help would be greatly appreciated! Here's the code:

```
public class Board extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6676924870723702476L;

    private Timer timer;
    private final int DELAY = 30;

    private ActionListener drawLine;
    private Ellipse2D circ;
    private ArrayList<Ellipse2D> circles = new ArrayList<>();

    private double circDiam = 80;
    private double circX = 0;
    private double circY = 0;
    private short circNum = 1;

    public Board() {

        drawLine = (ActionEvent e) -> {

            repaint();

            circX += circDiam;

            if(circNum == 5)
            {
                circNum = 1;            
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer(DELAY, drawLine);
        timer.start();
    }

    private Color getCircColor(short circNum) { 
        switch(circNum) {
            case 1:
                return Color.blue;
            case 2:
                return Color.red;
            case 3:
                return Color.yellow;
            case 4:
                return Color.green;
            default:
                return Color.gray;
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Dimension size = new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight());
        double width = size.getWidth();
        double height = size.getHeight();

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        RenderingHints rHints = new  RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        rHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(rHints);

        if(circX >= width - circDiam)
        {
            circY += circDiam;
            circX = 0;
            circDiam *= 0.865   ;
        }

        if(circY >= height - circDiam) {
            timer.stop();
        }

        circ = new Ellipse2D.Double(circX, circY, circDiam, circDiam);
        g2d.setColor(getCircColor(circNum));
        circNum++;
        circles.add(circ);

        for(Ellipse2D circ : circles) {
            g2d.fill(circ);
        }
    }

}

public class Execute extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3483390877436935589L;

    public Execute() {

        add(new Board());

        setSize(800, 800);
        setResizable(false);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            Execute ex = new Execute();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A painting method is for painting only. It should NOT:

1. create objects. That is don't create your Circle objects.
2. stop the Timer.
3. the painting code will simply iterate through the ArrayList to paint all the Cirlce objects.

The ActionListener of the Timer is used to:

1. create the Cirlce objects and add them to the ArrayList one at a time.
2. determine the Color of each object
3. stop the Timer when the desired number of objects has been created.

So basically in your Board class you need a method like `addCircle(....)`. This will add the Circle object to the ArrayList and then invoke `repaint()` on itself. You then change the `ActionListener` code to create the Circle object and invoke the `addCirle(...)` method.

> I guess the problem is color is not associated with each object

Correct. You will need a custom object to do your painting. This custom object will contain two properties:

1. the Circle object
2. the Color of the Circle object.

Or the other option is to paint directly to a BufferedImage and then just display the BufferedImage in the panel.

See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for example of both of these approaches for painting.

Comment: Hi, thank for the reply! Check the answer I posted with the code. I added the alterations you suggested but it still didn't work. Got same result, but with an exception, could you take a look? Trying to find the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I did everything @camickr said, I got the same result, but with an exception, here's the code:

```
public class Board extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6676924870723702476L;

    private Timer timer;
    private final int DELAY = 30;

    private ActionListener drawLine;
    private RCircle circ;
    private ArrayList<RCircle> circles = new ArrayList<>();

    private double circDiam = 80;
    private double circX = 0;
    private double circY = 0;
    private short circNum = 1;

    private double height = 800;
    private double width = 800;

    public Board() {

        drawLine = (ActionEvent e) -> {

            if(circX >= width - circDiam)
            {
                circY += circDiam;
                circX = 0;
                circDiam *= 0.865   ;
            }

            if(circY >= height - circDiam) {
                timer.stop();
            }

            circ = new RCircle(circX, circY, circDiam, circNum);

            circNum++;

            addCircle();

            circX += circDiam;

            if(circNum == 5)
            {
                circNum = 1;            
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer(DELAY, drawLine);
        timer.start();
    }

    private void addCircle() {
        circles.add(circ);

        repaint();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        RenderingHints rHints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        rHints.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHints(rHints);

        g2d.setColor(circ.getColor());

        for(RCircle circ : circles) {
            g2d.fill(circ.getCirc());
        }
    }

}


public class RCircle {

    private Ellipse2D circ;
    private Color color;

    public RCircle(double x, double y, double circDiam, short circNum) {
         this.circ = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, circDiam, circDiam);

         this.color = getCircColor(circNum);
    }

    private Color getCircColor(short circNum) { 
        switch(circNum) {
            case 1:
                return Color.blue;
            case 2:
                return Color.red;
            case 3:
                return Color.yellow;
            case 4:
                return Color.green;
            default:
                return Color.gray;
        }
    }

    public Ellipse2D getCirc() {
        return circ;
    }

    public void setCirc(Ellipse2D circ) {
        this.circ = circ;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}


public class Execute extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3483390877436935589L;

    public Execute() {

        add(new Board());

        setSize(800, 800);
        setResizable(false);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            Execute ex = new Execute();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: but with an exception, - so look at the Exception. The trace will tell you the line number of the statement that is causing the problem. This is basic problem solving and you should include the statement causing the problem when you ask a question. Once you see the statement, it should be obvious that you can't reference the "circ" variable outside the for loop.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much! I was really tired by that point last night and ended up not double checking the statement with the error, that was pretty easy to solve hahahaha Thanks again and have a great day!